# How to send button value to PHP backend (POST) using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, post, backend

I need to take this button value:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary view_data2" id=" <?php echo $row['idFuncionarios']; ?>" value = "<?php echo $row['dia']; ?>" name = "envio">Ver</button></td>`

And send it ($row['dia']) to the backend via POST method.

I already have this ajax function, which takes the button id and sends it to the same url I want using POST!

```
            $('.view_data2').click(function() {
                var employee_id2 = $(this).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/accomUser.inc.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        employee_id2: employee_id2
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#employee_detail2').html(data);
                        $('#adddata2').modal("show");
                    }
                });

                $('#addmodal2').modal("show");
            });
        });
```

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the value of the button to the backend via POST by using this code

```
$('.view_data2').click(function() {
    var employee_id2 = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/accomUser.inc.php",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            employee_id2: employee_id2,
            button_value: $(this).val() // $(this).val() will return value attribute
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#employee_detail2').html(data);
            $('#adddata2').modal("show");
        }
    });

    $('#addmodal2').modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, James. It worked! Sometimes I just can't think in this easy things! If i wanted to send, like, values that are shown in my front end: like ```<td><?php echo $row['nomeDepartamento']; ?> </td>``` that has nothing to do with the button, how would i send it via the same ajax? Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should use a <form> to surround the codes, then you can use <input type="hidden" name="{your data name} value="{your value}"/> then change the button type to submit, and use jQuery to handle the on submit function, you can use $(this).serializeArray() to get all value inside the form.